# How do I set up a work environment for both Mac and Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, macos, reactjs, web

I was wondering, how can I set up an environment for both Mac and Windows? I have a Mac laptop that I travel with and a Windows machine at home. I'd love to be able to develop with both machines interchangeably. For the most part I write web applications with create-react-app and rails. I've noticed that whenever I push my work to GitHub, pull onto a machine with a different OS, it doesn't play well, maybe because they may have different dependencies. Any tips or tutorials that you could link me too? I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: *"Something is wrong. Please help"* is not the type of question you should be asking on Stack Overflow. Ask a *specific* question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cloud IDE. Cloud9 works like a charm for me, and I'm usually writing code irrespective of whether I'm on desktop or mac. The IDE that I use gives me personalized Ubuntu workspaces for my projects.

You can also access your account on remote PCs, (such as if you're attending a hackathon), so your development environment takes less time to setup.